# Exception catch string is not allowing equation to process correctly

Tags: c++, exception

I have created an solution that compiles correctly, but when I enter in the required input it provides only a value of '0' which is not correct.  It started when I amended the code to have exception handling but for some reason now, the code no longer processes.  The first three input values can be anything and it will still output '0' when run.  Thoughts?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;
class MortgageCalc
{
private:
    double loan, interest;
    int years;
public:
    MortgageCalc() = default;
    void setLoan(double l) { loan = l; }  //mutator
    void setIntrest(double i) { interest = i; }     //mutator
    void setYears(short y) { years = y; }     //mutator
    double getMonthlyDue(double term) { return ((loan * ((interest / 100) / 12) * term) / (term - 1)); }  //constructor to run math calculation on montly loan amou
    double getTotalDue(double term) { return (getMonthlyDue(term) * (years * 12)); }  //constructor to compute total amount with interest
    double getTotalInt(double term) { return (getTotalDue(term) - loan); }
};

int main()
{
    MortgageCalc mort1;
    int choice = 0;
    int years = 0;
    double term(0), loan(0), interest(0);

    cout << "Enter the total loan amount on your mortgage loan: $";  //established loan variable
    {
        std::string loan;
        try
        {
            cin >> loan;
        }
        catch (string loan) //Exception for comma in 'loan' input by user
        {
            if (loan.find_first_not_of("0123456789.") != std::string::npos)   // npos invalid pseudo-index
            {
                std::cerr << "bad input, must use whole numbers only\n" << endl;
                return 1;
            }
            std::istringstream ins(loan);    // Converts the string into a number without punctuation
            ins >> loan;
        }
    }
    //       cout << "Loan amount cannot be negative. Enter the amount: ";
    mort1.setLoan(loan);

    cout << "Enter the interest rate (in whole #'s only): ";  //establishes interest rate variable
    cin >> interest; {
        if (interest <= 0) {  //example if you put 0 or negative # an exception will throw
            throw std::invalid_argument("received negative value");  //example #2 of negative throw exception
        }
    }

    //       cout << "Interest rate cannot be negative. Enter the amount: ";
    mort1.setIntrest(interest);

    cout << "Enter the length of the loan in years: "; //establishes term of payments
    while (!(cin >> years) || years < 0)
        cout << "Remainder of loan period cannot be negative. Enter the amount: ";
    mort1.setYears(years);
    term = pow((1 + ((interest / 100) / 12)), (12 * years));  //simple interest calculation with power calc to establish whole number translation

    while (choice != 3)   //loop for menu options and clean function exit
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Program to Calculate Mortgage Payments" << endl <<
            "1. Monthly Payment" << endl <<
            "2. Total Payment" << endl <<
            "3. Exit" << endl << endl <<
            "Enter an option above: ";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
            cout << "Monthly payment due is " << mort1.getMonthlyDue(term) << "." << endl;
        else if (choice == 2)
            cout << "Total amount for entire loan payments plus interest is $" << mort1.getTotalDue(term) << "." << endl <<
            "Total Interest Paid for this loan amount  $" << mort1.getTotalInt(term) << "." << endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @NathanOliver I appreciate the response, but I have a good debugger, but it does not walk you through the validation of math functions if the code compiles correctly.

Comment: It should if you set a breakpoint at the start of the program and then walk through the code line by line.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am a newbie so that is a bit above my head when it comes to evaluating based upon break points.

Comment: No better time to learn then now.

Comment: @NathanOliver if I didn't ask, I wouldn't be learning, do you think I have been sitting doing nothing, I have spent hours going through this and trying to figure out my mistake.  I am asking for help so that I know WHAT i did wrong.  I dont need someone telling me to go RTFM that is not what this community is for.

Comment: Sorry.  I am just trying to teach you how to solve something like this by yourself in a minute or two instead of having to come to Stack Overflow and spend all the time to ask a question and get an answer.  I'll add an answer but I really do suggest you learn how to step through your code so you can see how it is being executed.  It will be invaluable later on in programming.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when you do

```
mort1.setLoan(loan);
```

`loan` will always be `0` unless `cin >> loan;` throws an `std::sting`.  When you use

```
{
    std::string loan;
    try
    {
        cin >> loan;
    }
    catch (string loan) //Exception for comma in 'loan' input by user
    {
        if (loan.find_first_not_of("0123456789.") != std::string::npos)   // npos invalid pseudo-index
        {
            std::cerr << "bad input, must use whole numbers only\n" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        std::istringstream ins(loan);    // Converts the string into a number without punctuation
        ins >> loan;
    }
}
```

You have your conversion code from a string into the double<sup>1</sup> in the catch statement.  You will only ever enter that statement if `cin >> loan;` throws a `std::string` which I do not believe will ever happen.  Since you never actually update the value of `loan` in `main` it stays at the `0` you initialized it with.

You should only be doing error handling in the catch block.  The code to convert the string to a double should be handled outside the catch block.  I think you need to revisit how exceptions work and you should also look into how scopes can hide names from the outer scope.

<sup>1</sup> This is also not going to work since you are hiding the `double loan` from `main` with the `string loan` declared inside the sub scope.  You need to use different names for the variables in the sub scope.

Comment: thank you for telling me the application wont work.  Any thoughts on what my best path to fixing it is?  You keep telling to me to RTFM, but that does not provide any sort of solution support.

Comment: @haynstyle I added a little to the answer.  specifically *You should only be doing error handling in the catch block. The code to convert the string to a double should be handled outside the catch block.*

Comment: I REALLY NEED help on this gang, it is due tomorrow and I am completely lost!  Please help!